# Multiple impl candidate while deriving an instance in Rust

Tags: rust

When trying to use `rustc-serialize` to (d)e(n)code a `struct` containing two `String`s in Rust 1.7, the compiler complains that there are too many impl candidates and doesn't know which one to choose.

The code:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable, Debug)]
struct gonet {
    ip: String,
    mask: String,
}
```

The complaint:

```
src/bin/measurer.rs:18:5: 18:15 error: multiple applicable items in scope [E0034]
src/bin/measurer.rs:18     ip: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:18:5: 18:15 help: run `rustc --explain E0034` to see a detailed explanation
src/bin/measurer.rs:18:5: 18:15 note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` for the type `str`
src/bin/measurer.rs:18     ip: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:18:5: 18:15 note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` for the type `collections::string::String`
src/bin/measurer.rs:18     ip: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:18:5: 18:15 note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl of the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` for the type `&_`
src/bin/measurer.rs:18     ip: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:18:5: 18:15 note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl of the trait `radix_trie::keys::TrieKey` for the type `_`
src/bin/measurer.rs:18     ip: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:19:5: 19:17 error: multiple applicable items in scope [E0034]
src/bin/measurer.rs:19     mask: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:19:5: 19:17 help: run `rustc --explain E0034` to see a detailed explanation
src/bin/measurer.rs:19:5: 19:17 note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` for the type `str`
src/bin/measurer.rs:19     mask: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:19:5: 19:17 note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` for the type `collections::string::String`
src/bin/measurer.rs:19     mask: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:19:5: 19:17 note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl of the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Encodable` for the type `&_`
src/bin/measurer.rs:19     mask: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
src/bin/measurer.rs:19:5: 19:17 note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl of the trait `radix_trie::keys::TrieKey` for the type `_`
src/bin/measurer.rs:19     mask: String,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/bin/measurer.rs:16:26: 16:40 note: in this expansion of #[derive_RustcEncodable] (defined in src/bin/measurer.rs)
```

My code also use the [`TrieKey`](https://michaelsproul.github.io/rust_radix_trie/src/radix_trie/keys.rs.html#55) trait from the `radix_tree` crate, which also has an `encode()` method.

I'd like to have both traits in scope as I use them both, but they conflict, so how can I specify which trait of `String` to use for deriving (if it is even possible)?

Not `use`ing `TrieKey` works, but I'd like a solution that allows me to `use` both.

Comment: This is *really* strange. [This](https://gist.github.com/netvl/4c7afffc7ed8ec72717acd3e8617d1c0) program contains only your structure, and it compiles just fine. Try to extract your struct in a separate module, with as little `use`s as possible, and check whether it compiles. It also *may* be some interference with dependency crates, although as far as I understand, Rust trait rules were designed exactly to avoid problems like this.

Comment: [MCVE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4855336da123370b3fdd9ef689917453&version=stable&backtrace=0) This is a hygiene bug in the expansion of `derive(RustcEncodable)`.

Comment: Thanks, reported [here](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustc-serialize/issues/151).

Comment: and fixed [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32908)

Answer (score 0):

As said under the comments on the original post, this is actually [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustc-serialize/issues/151). A fix is now [available](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32908).